# OpenLayers 6: How to calculate the distance between two points (clickable) from api?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, openlayers, distance, points

I have some points declared on api.py file as so:

```
(...)
@app.route('/api/pontos/', methods=['GET'])
def get_pontos():
    return jsonify({
        'pontos': [
            [-44.3001,-2.52001, 3, "name1"],
            [-44.309468, -2.509284, 4, "name2"],
            [-44.307802, -2.557744, 5, "name3"],
(...)
```

From which I can select each point and it shows on browser some characteristics about it

```
var selec = new ol.interaction.Select()
selec.getFeatures().on('add', function(e){

    var label = typeof (e.element.getProperties().text) != 'undefined' ? e.element.getProperties().text : ''
    if(label != ''){
        alert(e.element.getProperties().text)
    }

})

(...)

function loadPoints(){
    axios.get(`/api/pontos`)
        .then(function(response){
            if(response.status === 200){
                var coordsArray = response.data.pontos;

                coordsArray.map(coords =>{

                    var point = new ol.Feature({
                        geometry : new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.fromLonLat(coords)), 
                        text : `Preco: ${coords[2]} reais, Bar:${coords[3]} `
                    });

                    point.setStyle(pointStyle);
                    vectorSource.addFeature(point)
                }); 

                //Fit nos pontos
                map.getView().fit(vectorSource.getExtent());
            }

        })
}

loadShape('ma')
loadPoints()
```

But what if I want to click on two points and calculate the distance between them so it can show it on browser?

I tried seeing the documentation and some other questions but I can't seem to adapt them to my specific problem.

Comment: Try something similar to this https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/measure.html

Answer (score 1):

you can use getDistance() very simple function to calculate distance between two coordinates.

```
calculateDistance(toLonLat(first) , toLonLat(second));
function calculateDistance(src , dest ){
let finalmeasure = getDistance(src , dest);
//let finalmeasure = Math.round(line.getLength() * 100) / 100; //for rounding
console.log(finalmeasure); //in meter unit
}
```

best regards